# Redirect URL to external URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to be able to redirect this URL:

www.shorturl.co.uk/answers

To this URL:

http://actual.url.co.uk/answers.html

I have tried the following in .htaccess but it doesn't appear to be working:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.shorturl\.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^answers$ http://actual.url.co.uk/answers.html [L,R=301,NC]
```

Can anyone point out where I might be going wrong? Thanks

Comment: do you actually own the "shorturl" domain?

Comment: yes, we own both domains

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in this, but you could give it a try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.shorturl\.co\.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^shorturl\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule ^answers$ http://actual.url.co.uk/answers.html [R=301,L]
```